# Can std::async call std::function objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdasync

Is it possible to call function objects created with std::bind using std::async. The following code fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Adder {
public:
    int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Adder a;
    function<int(int, int)> sumFunc = bind(&Adder::add, &a, 1, 2);
    auto future = async(launch::async, sumFunc); // ERROR HERE
    cout << future.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

No matching function for call to 'async': 
 Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with *Fp = std::*_1::function &, *Args = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::*_1::__invoke_of, >

Is it just not possible to use async with std::function objects or am I doing something wrong?

(This is being compiled using Xcode 5 with the Apple LLVM 5.0 compiler)

Comment: where would `async` get the functor arguments from? Try passing an `std::function<void()>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible to call function objects created with `std::bind` using `std::async`

Yes, you can call any functor, as long as you provide the right number of arguments.

> am I doing something wrong?

You're converting the bound function, which takes no arguments, to a `function<int(int,int)>`, which takes (and ignores) two arguments; then trying to launch that with no arguments.

You could specify the correct signature:

```
function<int()> sumFunc = bind(&Adder::add, &a, 1, 2);
```

or avoid the overhead of creating a `function`:

```
auto sumFunc = bind(&Adder::add, &a, 1, 2);
```

or not bother with `bind` at all:

```
auto future = async(launch::async, &Adder::add, &a, 1, 2);
```

or use a lambda:

```
auto future = async(launch::async, []{return a.add(1,2);});
```